# CIP(Common Industrial Protocol) : How to Send a Get_Attribute_all packet?

Tags: c#, protocols, ethernet, plc, industrial

I wanted to send a CIP packet to the PLC  requesting for the TCPIP interface object. I have successfully registered a session and did a forward open. I am stuck on how to get the PLC to send me the TCPIP interface object details. Can any one point me to the right direction?

I am writing an application in C#.

Comment: This depends on a few things. What is the PLC model you are trying to communicate with?

Comment: I am trying to communicate to a Allen Bradley compact logix.

Comment: As I remember if you want to use CIP, then you need to have Ethernet/IP lib to make it work. If you are not looking for CIP Safety, then you can find multiple examples on internet how to establish communication between PC and AB PLC. Here is one of the examples: https://www.mesta-automation.com/how-to-communicate-to-an-allen-bradley-plc-with-c-and-libplctag-ethernet-ip-library/